# How to select correct com.crealytics:spark-excel package in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-excel, maven-repository

I am trying to install package com.crealytics:spark-excel package in databricks under maven repository.
but the package installation is still in pending state.
How to select com.crealytics:spark-excel package to install in databricks and on what basis.
Can anyone please help me to understand.

All valuable suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed the `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.5`

**Step 1:** Navigate to the Cluster page and Compute in Databricks.

**Step 2:** Click on the tab **Libraries** -> **Install new**.

**Step 3:** Select **Maven** as a Library source

[image]

**Step 4:** Click on the Search packages

[image]

**Step 5:** Select the Maven central as in the below image
[image]

Step 6: Choose desired pacakge from the Maven Central based on the **Scala** and **Spark** version
[image]

For an example I have installed the bleow Vesrion.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can you please let me know which runtime version in databricks ,you are using.

Comment: I am using the 13.2

Comment: I have tried using same setting the package is not installing, but its working with 10.4LTS setting. Can you please suggest on this. I would li ke to go for higher spark 3.2 above but not excel library is not installing with 3.2 aove versions

Comment: try installing com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.13:3.5.0_0.20.1